# PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class ‘grid_map_rviz_plugin/GridMap‘ failed to load

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
can someone help me with this error?

```
lucas@lucas-VirtualBox:~$ source /home/lucas/projects/imagine/build/devel/setup.bash 
lucas@lucas-VirtualBox:~$ rviz
[ INFO] [1547197031.245982719]: rviz version 1.12.16
[ INFO] [1547197031.246442344]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1547197031.246692910]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1547197031.735517498]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1547197031.736545820]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ERROR] [1547197038.107183504]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'grid_map_rviz_plugin/GridMap' failed to load.  Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin grid_map_rviz_plugin/GridMap. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
lucas@lucas-VirtualBox:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312453/pluginlibfactory:-the-plugin-for-class-%E2%80%98grid_map_rviz_plugin/gridmap%E2%80%98-failed-to-load/) by [LucLucLuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39414/luclucluc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-11**:
Not without a verbatim copy-paste of the full error.

**Comment by [LucLucLuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39414/luclucluc/) on 2019-01-11**:
i want to include a image. But it doesnt work. I dont now why. It shows ">5 points required to upload files" I try wih Chrom/ Internet Explorer - jpg/png/ and pdf ---- do you have any idea?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-11**:
There is absolutely no need for attaching images. Error messages are *text* and can be copy-pasted, verbatim, from the terminal window into your question. Please do so.

**Comment by [LucLucLuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39414/luclucluc/) on 2019-01-11**:
thanks for your fast answers. I followed your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you actually installed the [wiki/grid_map_rviz_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/grid_map_rviz_plugin) package?

---

Edit: and seeing this:

> lucas@lucas-VirtualBox:~$ source /home/lucas/projects/imagine/build/devel/setup.bash

can you tell us how you've setup your workspace?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucLucLuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39414/luclucluc/) on 2019-01-11**:
Oh nice, i actually installed the wiki/grid_map_rviz_plugin package - it works. But i want to creat a package independent project in c++..

Why do I have to install the package? Why can not cmake with catkin contain the necessary files?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-11**:\

> But i want to creat a package independent project in c++..

I don't understand what that means, but how do you expect things to work without having the plugin actually installed?

**Comment by [LucLucLuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39414/luclucluc/) on 2019-01-11**:
Why do I have to install the package? Why can not cmake with catkin contain the necessary files?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-11**:\

> Why can not cmake with catkin contain the necessary files?

?

CMake ~= Catkin are build tools. They don't contain any code other than what is needed to be able to build software.

You're sort-of asking: "why does Visual Studio not contain/provide MS Word?"